# Sed not deleting newlines from file

Tags: linux, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SED: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

I have the file with newlines. and I am trying this

`sed -re 's/\n//' sample1.txt` and it's not working

It's showing output with newlines and not removing them.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` splits the input it receives at newlines and removes them before running the sed script, i.e. the script will never see then newlines. Use tr instead:

```
tr -d '\n'
```

Or if you insist on `sed`, use *Guru's* looped solution which re-inserts `\n` with the `N` command.

Comment: Do you have any better solution with sed only. Thanks for `tr`  but i just want to know

Comment: @user1953864: No, this is not a job for sed, even with the looped solution you end up with a newline at the end. You should probably come up with a minimal example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

Use double quotes:

```
sed -e "s/\n//" sample1.txt
```

If your intention is to try and join all lines in a file:

```
sed -e :a  -e 'N;s/\n//;ta'  sample1.txt
```

Comment: i tried and it didn't work

Comment: @user1953864 : `sed` processes file line by line. so try `tr` instead

Comment: @user1953864: `tr -d '\n' < sample1.txt`

Comment: @Prince is there any way to do it with sed

Comment: @user1953864 : updated solution since you are looking to join all lines in a file

Comment: @user1953864: why do you need to use sed, [what are you actually trying to do](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)? Note that the second solution loads the entire file into memory.

Comment: -1 What's this? I'm seeing answers like this every day - misdirected guesses that changing to *weaker* quotes would fix a command.

Comment: @thor , Actually i am learning sed and thats why i wanted to get the solutiojn in sed. but thanks for telling that it will put all the file in memory. doing it on 2 Gb file will halt the sysytem. Any other way with sed??